# Printing a stackpanel containing a listbox over multiple pages wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, listbox

Hi I am looking to print a StackPanel that contains a listbox which can contain an infinite number of items and therefore needs to print over multiple pages. I found this code online and it works fine.

```
public static FixedDocument GetFixedDocument(FrameworkElement toPrint, PrintDialog printDialog)
    {
        if (printDialog == null)
        {
            printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        }
        var capabilities = printDialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDialog.PrintTicket);
        var pageSize = new Size(printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth, printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight);
        var visibleSize = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);
        var fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
        //If the toPrint visual is not displayed on screen we neeed to measure and arrange it  
        toPrint.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
        toPrint.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), toPrint.DesiredSize));
        //  
        var size = toPrint.DesiredSize;
        //Will assume for simplicity the control fits horizontally on the page  
        double yOffset = 0;
        while (yOffset < size.Height)
        {
            var vb = new VisualBrush(toPrint)
            {
                Stretch = Stretch.None,
                AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left,
                AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Top,
                ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute,
                TileMode = TileMode.None,
                Viewbox = new Rect(0, yOffset, visibleSize.Width, visibleSize.Height)
            };
            var pageContent = new PageContent();
            var page = new FixedPage();
            ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(page);
            fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);
            page.Width = pageSize.Width;
            page.Height = pageSize.Height;
            var canvas = new Canvas();
            FixedPage.SetLeft(canvas, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth);
            FixedPage.SetTop(canvas, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight);
            canvas.Width = visibleSize.Width;
            canvas.Height = visibleSize.Height;
            canvas.Background = vb;
            page.Children.Add(canvas);
            yOffset += visibleSize.Height;
        }
        return fixedDoc;
    }
```

However this causes certain items of a listbox to be cut off at the bottom of a page and continued on the next page (as shown below). Is it possible to modify this code in any way to determine the size of the page and if the current listboxitem does not fit onto this page that it starts on the next page? Quite new to all this so any help would be greatly appreciated.[image: Picture of issue]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar task once and came up with this code, which uses a 'dummy' renderer to determine the height of the element up front and then either adds it to the current page or creates a new one. For sure, that's not a very beautiful solution, but it did the job at the time. Maybe you can take sth. away from it.

```
Size A4Size = new Size(793.92, 1122.24);
Size InfiniteSize = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
var pages = new List<FrameworkElement>();
int pageNumber = 0;
var printDate = DateTime.Now;
var size = A4Size;

var currentPage = new Report(size, printDate);
currentPage.Render();

var listElements = new Queue<ElementsToPrint>(...);

var dummyRenderer = new Viewbox();
dummyRenderer.Child = currentPage;
dummyRenderer.Measure(InfiniteSize);
dummyRenderer.Arrange(new Rect(dummyRenderer.DesiredSize));
dummyRenderer.UpdateLayout();
var template = (DataTemplate)View.FindResource("ItemTemplate");

dummyRenderer.Child = null;

var availableHeight = currentPage.View.ActualHeight;

while (listElements.Count > 0)
{
    var elementToRender = listElements.Dequeue();
    dummyRenderer.Child = new ListViewItem()
    {
       Content = elementToRender,
       ContentTemplate = template,
       Foreground = Brushes.Black
    };
    dummyRenderer.Measure(InfiniteSize);
    dummyRenderer.Arrange(new Rect(dummyRenderer.DesiredSize));
    dummyRenderer.UpdateLayout();

    var renderedItem = (ListViewItem)dummyRenderer.Child;

    dummyRenderer.Child = null;


    var willItFit = availableHeight > renderedItem.ActualHeight;

    if (willItFit)
    {
        currentPage.DataListView.Items.Add(renderedItem);
        availableHeight -= renderedItem.ActualHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        dummyRenderer.Child = currentPage;
        dummyRenderer.Measure(InfiniteSize);
        dummyRenderer.Arrange(new Rect(dummyRenderer.DesiredSize));
        dummyRenderer.UpdateLayout();
        dummyRenderer.Child = null;

        pages.Add(currentPage);

        // Set up a new Page
        pageNumber++;

        currentPage = new DiaryReport(size,pageNumber,printDate,anonymous);

        dummyRenderer.Child = currentPage;
        dummyRenderer.Measure(InfiniteSize);
        dummyRenderer.Arrange(new Rect(dummyRenderer.DesiredSize));
        dummyRenderer.UpdateLayout();

        dummyRenderer.Child = null;

        availableHeight = currentPage.DataListView.ActualHeight;

        currentPage.DataListView.Items.Add(renderedItem);
        availableHeight -= renderedItem.ActualHeight;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much I'll give this a go!